# How to use find method in simple html dom when have multiple classes

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

If I have an element something like this

```
<h1 class="first second last">
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</h1>
```

I want to use find method only for these three classes. I tried like this :

```
$html->find('first.second.last',0)->plaintext;
```

But it's not working. Is there any idea to use find method for this type of condition?

Comment: Have you tried something like `getElementsByClassName()` ?

Comment: I don't want it in javascript or jquery. only for PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Comment: The css for that would be `.first.second.last`. Also `p` is not allowed inside of `h1`

Comment: I also tried .first.second.last in simple html dom but not working.Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.html :

```
<h1 class="first second last">
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</h1>
```

As I had to it in php simple html dom parser. 
I found a alternate solution for my query not by using find method but we can check multiple classes by using this:

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$html = file_get_html('test.html');
$h1 = $html->find('h1');
foreach ($h1 as $h1) {
    $h1Class = ($h1->class);
    if($h1Class == 'first second last'){
        $item['test'] = 'success';
    }else{
        $item['test'] = 'fail';
    }
    $ar[] = $item;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(document.getElementsByClassName("first second last"));
</script>
```

With this code you get your dom element.

Answer (score -1):

`getElementsByClassName()` is your solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var yourDomElement = document.getElementsByClassName("first second last"));
</script>
```

If you are using jQuery then you can also get same DOM by `(.)` operator:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var yourDomElement = (".first second last");
</script>
```

if you want get DOM by without javascript and jQuery then use this code:-

```
$dom_element_class = 'first second last';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $dom_element_class . "']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

This [link](http://www.binarytides.com/php-tutorial-parsing-html-with-domdocument/) will be useful.

Comment: but I want to use it in find method of simple html dom(php) not by javascript or jquery

Comment: @Paramjeet: Please check my edited answer. Hope it wil help you.